# ¿Como crear en css iconos con símbolos "+" y "-"?

Tags: css

Quisiera saber si es posible crear icon plus con circulo centrado como se ve en la imagen?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
.vc_tta-controls-icon-plus::before {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    border-width: 2px 0 0;
}
.vc_tta .vc_tta-controls-icon.vc_tta-controls-icon-plus::after {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    border-width: 0 0 0 2px;
}

<div class="vc_tta-panel-heading">
       <h4 class="vc_tta-panel-title vc_tta-controls-icon-position-left">
           <a href="#1479320323429-ebe4b3e2-08e5" data-vc-accordion="" data-vc-container=".vc_tta-container">
               <span class="vc_tta-title-text">A. DIRECCIÓN Y GERENCIA</span>
               <i class="vc_tta-controls-icon vc_tta-controls-icon-plus"></i>                     
           </a>
       </h4>
</div>
```

con esto solo obtengo los símbolos "+" y "-"

Comment: ¿Puedes añadir también el elemento al que se lo añades?

Comment: <div class="vc_tta-panel-heading"><h4 class="vc_tta-panel-title vc_tta-controls-icon-position-left"><a href="#1479320323429-ebe4b3e2-08e5" data-vc-accordion="" data-vc-container=".vc_tta-container"><span class="vc_tta-title-text">A. DIRECCIÓN Y GERENCIA</span><i class="vc_tta-controls-icon vc_tta-controls-icon-plus"></i></a></h4></div>
ES PARA UN ACORDEON DE VISUAL COMPOSER QUE ESTOY EDITANDO.

Comment: Con tu código no me aparece el + o -. Mira a ver si le falta algo. Puedes comprobarlo aquí: https://jsfiddle.net/ge73uhuz/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Te voy a poner una alternativa un poco diferente a la de aldanux pero que también se basa en el uso de `::before` y `::after`. La idea sería crear un botón que tenga el círculo azul y luego, dependiendo de la clase ponga una barra horizontal o una barra horizontal y otra vertical usando los bordes.

Algo como esto:

```css
.boton {
  display:inline-block;
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  border-radius:100%;
  border:2px solid #50a0d4;
  position:relative;
}

.boton.mas::before, .boton.menos::before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
  width:40%;
  height:0;
  border-top:3px solid #50a0d4;
}

.boton.mas::after {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
  width:0;
  height:40%;
  border-left:3px solid #50a0d4;
}
```

```html
<div class="boton menos"></div>
<div class="boton mas"></div>
```

Comment: +1 me gusta tu propuesta... más que la mia

Comment: Tu propuesta (con algún cambio mínimo) es mucho más flexible que la mía porque permite poner diferente contenido, mientras que mi solución es más específica para el caso de OP.

Answer (score 2):

Si es posible:

```css
.icon {
  width: 2em;  
  height: 2em;
  position: relative;
  color: #50a0d4;
  border: 2px solid #50a0d4;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.icon-minus:before,
.icon-plus:before {  
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
  bottom: 0; 
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
}

.icon-minus:before {  
  content: "\02212";  
}

.icon-plus:before {
  content: "\0002B";  
}
```

```html
<i class="icon icon-minus"></i>
<i class="icon icon-plus"></i>
```

Comment: Gracias, funciono!